# Is it possible to have fuzzinness only on some fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to add fuzziness to my elasticsearch query but I dont want it be on id fields. If I pass in an id to my query I want it to return only exact matches but I don't want to have to specify all the fields that I want to match on. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: you want to read the manual right here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: I didnt see anything in the manuals, were you sending a link to something specific in the documentation?

Comment: you can work with bool to differ for exakt matches and fuzziness on different fields. lets say you want exact on id OR fuzzy on fields =* (something like that).
therefore you did not add any query code there is no more specific answer to that right now